# How to print process id into statment

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have assigned a work to take take all process and make them into a statement. So I tried this script.

```
#!/bin/bash
a= ps | awk '{print $1}'
echo select $a
```

So I am getting this output

```
PID
1838
1839
1840
13226
select
```

I know that `a` variable is taking many arguments and unable to insert into one, but i am unable to get the logic.

I want a output similar to this.

```
select 1838, 1839, 1840, 13226
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have basic syntax errors for what you want to achieve. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/16072351/445621 for an example of command substitution into a shell variable.

Comment: Thanks @DanielAndersson Using this way I am not getting `select` and actually I want ','(comma) also in middle of them. And the pid is coming how can I restrict that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Updated answer

Use backticks `` or `$( )` to wrap the commands whose output will be saved as the variable.

Tail +2 to show all but the first line.

Awk adds the comma and spaces between the valuese

Sed removes the comma-space at the end of the line.

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$(ps | tail +2 | awk '{printf ("%s, ",$1)}' | sed "s/, $//")
echo select $a
```

#### Output

```
$ ./printpid.sh
select 2293836, 3276802, 6422606, 6750318, 7667882, 7798894, 8716412
```

Comment: @temp, You're welcome. I hope you're copy-pasting this and can backspace the last comma. Removing that one would be way harder for me!

Comment: Sorry @wally but can't we manipulate ',' because while auditing I am getting errors.

Comment: @temp, I don't understand. You want the comma at the end? You want a space after each comma? The space is easy. Just add a space after the `%s,` in the code.

Comment: my apologies if i am bugging you I go not want the comma(only one comma) at the end of the statment

Comment: @temp. Nope! Not bugging me. Here's a version without the last comma. And I added the spaces too.